Why is WebGPU performance so bad in my benchmark compared to WebGL?
Here's the code of my benchmark, tested it on Latest Chrome Canary on Win11 (with vsync disabled and fps unlocked).
WebGPU has around 1/3 the FPS of WebGL bench, I can't figure out why is that.
Code:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import WebGPURenderer from 'three/addons/renderers/webgpu/WebGPURenderer.js';
import Stats from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';

var stats0 = new Stats();
stats0.showPanel( 0 );
stats0.domElement.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;bottom:20px;left:0px;';
document.body.appendChild( stats0.dom );

function setupScene() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color("#0d0c18");
    return scene;
}

function setupCamera() {
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 16 / 9, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(1, 1, 100);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    return camera;
}

function setupWebGLRenderer() {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( 1600, 900 );
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
}

function setupWebGPURenderer() {
    const renderer = new WebGPURenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( 1600, 900 );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    return renderer;
}

function createGeometry(scene) {
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 32, 16 ); //Verts:482, Edges: 992, Faces: 512, Tris: 960
    const NUM_OBJECTS = 5000;
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OBJECTS; i++) {
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide, color: 0x00ff00 });
        const cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cubeMesh.position.x = Math.random() * 200 - 105;
        cubeMesh.position.y = Math.random() * 110 - 55;
        cubeMesh.position.z = Math.random() * 100 - 80;
        scene.add(cubeMesh);
    }
}

async function animate(scene, camera, renderer, rendererType, stats0) {
    async function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        if (rendererType === 'webgl')
        {
            await renderer.clear();
        } else {
            await renderer.clearAsync();
        }
        
        scene.traverse((object) => {
            if (object instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                object.rotation.x += 0.005;
                object.rotation.y += 0.01;
            }
        });

        if (rendererType === 'webgl')
        {
            await renderer.render(scene, camera);
        } else {
            await renderer.renderAsync(scene, camera);
        }

        //fps counter
        stats0.update();
    }
    
    await render();
}

export function loadGeometryBenchmark(rendererType, stats0) {

    const scene = setupScene();
    const camera = setupCamera();
    let renderer = null
    if (rendererType === 'webgl')
    {
        console.info('WebGL selected');
        renderer = setupWebGLRenderer();
    } else {
        console.info('WebGPU selected'); 
        renderer = setupWebGPURenderer();
    }
    createGeometry(scene);
    animate(scene, camera, renderer, rendererType, stats0);
}

I want to make some simple benchmarks comparing WebGL and WebGPU performance in typical scenarios and I am wondering if I should stick to THREE library or start from scratch.
I tried changing multiple flags in chrome settings, I also made sure that WebGPU hardware acceleration is working.
Also, when I look at HWinfo when testing WebGPU benchmark CPU usage increases and GPU usage decreases compared to WebGL, which is the opposite result of what I was expecting.
